# Extjs htmleditor get cursor position

Tags: extjs

{

```
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        name: 'msg',
        value : 'abcd',
        id: 'myeditor',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(t2){  
                var but = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    text: 'Click me',
                    handler: function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('myeditor').insertAtCursor('bbbb');                      
                    }
                });

                t2.getToolbar().add(but)
            }
        }
    }
```

If cursers is not in the html editor I wont to insert 'bbbb' at the end of 'abcd' and if curser in any point in the editor wont to insert 'bbbb' at the curser point. Can you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've used this workaroud:

```
var before = Ext.getCmp('yourHtmlEditor').getValue();
Ext.getCmp('yourHtmlEditor').insertAtCursor('something');
var after = Ext.getCmp('noteEditor').getValue();
if (before==after) {       
    Ext.getCmp('yourHtmlEditor').setValue(before+'something');
}
```